# Multi consumer dequeue in DPDK framework

Tags: dpdk

Is it possible to implement a ring buffer in DPDK in which a single object is enqueued by a single producer can be dequeued by multiple consumers(say 4 consumers)?. i.e.,..Is the object dequeued by the 1st consumer in the ring buffer available to another consumers?

Answer (score 0):

DPDK rings are just pointers to buffers, the enqueue/dequeue operations are quite cheap. So the best solution comes to mind is to create 4 queues and enqueue the same object 4 times to 4 different queues.

There might be issues with freeing this object. Have a look into the mbuf reference counter.

And there might be issues with simultaneous modification of the object. Have a look at locks or other synchronization mechanisms.